# Display PlaceHolder Text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a countdown timer textfield that displays 60 as a placeholder (grey).  When I start the timer, it goes black and starts counting down.  At the end, I invalidate the timer and set the countdown textfield back to 60.  Of course, it's black now.  How do I get it back to the placeholder text of 60 (meaning that it's grey) without resorting to a hack using NSAttributedString?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the TextField's text to nil or the empty string, @"". will cause the placeholder text to be displayed.

Comment: Weird, according to the 10.5 docs:

Placeholder strings, set using setPlaceholderString: or setPlaceholderAttributedString:, now appear in the text field cell if the actual string is nil or @"". They are drawn in grey on the cell and are not archived in the “pre-10.2” nib format.

Comment: Erik: I can't find any mention of setPlaceholderString in the docs... 

Peter: [countdownTextField setStringValue:nil];

Comment: NSTextFieldCell implements setPlaceholderString, and NSTextField in turn has an embedded NSTextFieldCell.  I was setting a NSTextField's contents to empty using [textField setStringValue:@""].

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the "value" binding on the NSTextField, you will need to set the Null Placeholder for the binding instead of for the text cell's placeholder. The empty string (@"" ) does seem to count as a null value for the purposes of the placeholder.

Comment: Can you add some details, please.

Comment: Are you configuring bindings via Interface Builder? If so, what specifically is unclear?

Comment: Yes, 'value' binding in IB. Placeholder for `NSTextFieldCell` displayed when it text is nil or empty string. Value taken from property bonded to is `nil`. So, why we need "to set the Null Placeholder for the binding instead of for the text cell's placeholder"? Why placeholder just not work? Is there documented anywhere? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find any *direct* official documentation specific to this, but to me the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25508937/179583 makes some sense and might lead you in the right direction — if you use bindings but don't provide the bindings placeholder, the missing (i.e. `nil`) value for the null placeholder *there* must override the text field's own placeholder value. The resonse at http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/Jun/msg01502.html also says ± the same thing as I discovered in practice here — you need to set the *bindings* placeholder if you are using bindings at all.